# How to jump directly to a column number in Vim

Tags: vim

Sometimes for debugging purposes I have to do the exciting job of wading through minified javascript code. The lines are upto 600 columns wide. The exception reporting library is kind enough to provide me the exact crash coordinates in the form of line number and column number. However I can't find a way to directly jump to the column number, even though I can jump to the line so easily.

How can I do it?

Comment: It sounds like this a tool that needs to be invented.  "Deminify my js, and while you're at it jump to the spot identified by this column number."

Comment: @dnellis74 That tool exists. It's called "sourcemaps" ;)

Comment: // , @Burgi, can haz 3 word summary & link?

Answer (score 451, accepted):

The `|` command does what you want, as in <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> will take you to column 30.

```
                                                        bar
|                       To screen column [count] in the current line.
                        exclusive motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe.
```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#bar

Comment: Be aware, for general usage, that this is *screen* column, not *real* column. This means that `<Tab>` characters will get different results. If these characters will be there, you will instead want `|30lh` or `|29l` or `029l` or something like that.

Comment: You can also pass a number before various motion commands, e.g. `50h` will move 50 characters left.

Comment: `:set nowrap` may also help reduce confusion between screen lines and file lines.

Comment: @DavidPope: note that in this case "screen columns" means that it's still relative to the start of the line. `g0` achieves "start of current screen line".

Comment: The vim documentation is hilarious: "Ceci n'est pas une pipe" :-)

Comment: When I do this, it only moves by char-count (not by column-count). How can I get this working?

Answer (score 85):

You can use the `cursor` function. For example, to jump to column 25 of line 15, you can use `:call cursor(15,25)`.

Comment: This does give an answer to the question and it's convenient having the Ex command alternative for scripting. Note that if the line number is zero, the cursor will stay in the current line.

Comment: This is especially nice for opening Vim from other tools, as this call can be done on the command-line: `"+call cursor($LINE,$COLUMN)"`

Answer (score 18):

An alternative answer that works for me on Mac OS is to use the command that moves the cursor to the right (i.e. `l`). So if your cursor is on the first column, and you want to put the cursor at column 50 of your current line, use the command:

```
49l
```

Comment: I use this all the time, but the good ol `:21` (enter) `049l` felt like a lot of work to get to a specific location, so that's why I came upon this question lol

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> takes you to the 80th column - if your line has that many columns, that is, and from anywhere in the current line.

also: this is a pipe sign, not the lowercase letter 'L'